# SmartTarget Content Selection: Component Template List is empty

Tags: smarttarget

When setting up promotions with SmartTarget 2014 SP1 I can get everything to work just fine if my content selection is based on a folder, but if I try to select components individually, the dropdown for selecting a Component Template is empty, both for a common Component Template, and also if I check the *Select per Item* checkbox. I have the same issue whether I create promotions on a master publication level (valid for all child publications) or on a local publication level.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, or how to get this working properly?

**UPDATE**: My Component Templates are 'dynamic' - *Set to Published as a Dynamic Component* with the *Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly* checkbox unchecked (these are standalone banners for SmartTarget only). I notice that when I check the checkbox, the CT appears in the list. Is this as intended? I would expect that it shouldn't matter if this box is checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses the same logic as when you select a Component Presentation to put on a Page: it will look at the Schemas the Components are based on and find any Component Templates that are linked to those Schemas.

Comment: See my update above - it works when the Allow on Page... checkbox is checked - which doesnt really make sense to me

Comment: My neither. I guess the API method SmartTarget uses only returns items that can be placed on a page. I would consider that a defect.

Comment: OK - thanks - I will report it to customer support